# Project Explorer Tree Color for Eclipse Moonrise on Windows 8.1

Tags: eclipse, svn

I'm using Moonrise with Juno and want to change the Project Explorer foreground color for some tree items.

Some of my items are grey. I think it comes from SVN colors or so. But whatever I change in Windows - Preferences - General - Appearance . Colors and Fonts - SVN ... nothing happens anywhere in the UI.

Also my package and class names are grey.

I'm using Moonrise with Jeeeyul's Theme. All predefined.

Here is a screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

I want all labels to be white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it. It's Mylyn which is not working with dark themes.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=321336#c7

See post 7. You have to deactivate the task decoration.

Answer (score 1):

Try Eclipse -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Label Decorations -> Disable "Git"

Comment: Not only MyLyn one but you also have to disable "Git". Thanks Macy!